# Java8 CompletionStage content

Tags: java, json, rx-java, reactive-programming

How do I actually get the content of this:

```
RxClient<RxCompletionStageInvoker> newRxClient = RxCompletionStage.newClient(); 
        CompletionStage<Response> stage = newRxClient
                  .target("somelink")
                   .request()
                    .rx()                   
                    .get()
                    .toCompletableFuture();
```

Instead of:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@5ba3f27a[Completed normally]
```

Comment: What do you want as an output? Could you give an example?

Comment: The link gives back json, I want to get that json as output.

Answer (score 0):

I guese you called:

```
 System.out.println(stage);
```

Which calls `stage.toString()` which prints the (CompatibleFuture) object, but not its content. To get the content of a Future object you simply use `stage.get()`. So the following should give you a representation of the Response object (and the json String if that is returned by `Response#toString()`)

```
 System.out.println(stage.get());
```

I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Yours is almost what I was looking for: stage.get() says that get is undefined for stage but stage.toCompletableFuture().get() works. Thanks for the input anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `toCompletableFuture()` and then `get()` works:

```java
stage.toCompletableFuture().get()
```

as per OP @Rauno's prior edit to the question.